# Complex assotiations in FactoryGirl mockup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, tdd, factory-bot

I need to create some complex mockups for my app where I need to reuse one of fields of model. I wanna do it like

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Testowa #{n}" }

    full_amount 10_000

    pay_date DateTime.now + 7.days

    association :clienr
    company client.company
  end
end
```

But then I get error `undefined method`company' for #`. I need it badly to test my app and I couldn't find anything in docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed that by making `company` lazy evaluated assigment

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Testowa #{n}" }

    full_amount 10_000

    pay_date DateTime.now + 7.days

    association :clienr
    company { client.company }
  end
end
```